# bash_profile is not taking effect with chef-run

Tags: environment-variables, chef-infra, bash, env

If I run the below recipe with chef, entries are getting added in `~/.bash_profile`, but when I do `echo $PATH` or `echo $JAVA_HOME`, the command line returns blank values. What's going on there?

```
ruby_block  "set-env-java-home" do
  block do
    ENV["JAVA_HOME"] = node['java']['path']
    ENV['PATH'] = "#{ENV['PATH']}:#{node['java']['path']}/bin"
  end
  not_if { $JAVA_HOME == "#{ENV['JAVA_HOME']}" && $PATH = "#{ENV['PATH']}:#{node['java']['path']}/bin" }
end

bash 'set-env-bashrc' do
  code <<-EOH
    echo -e "export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" >> ~/.bash_profile
    echo -e "export PATH=$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
    source ~/.bash_profile
  EOH
end
```

Comment: Maybe this resolved issue (and its references) provides some insight: [COOK-573:
Java Cookbook should set $JAVA_HOME when it installs java so the rest of the chef-client run will have it available](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-573).

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things here:

### Your `not_if` is wrong

```
not_if { $JAVA_HOME == "#{ENV['JAVA_HOME']}" && $PATH = "#{ENV['PATH']}:#{node['java']['path']}/bin" }
```

You are confusing Ruby and bash here. IN Ruby `$JAVA_HOME` refers to a global constant. It's unclear to me what your `not_if` guard is trying to accomplish, but using it as-is is certainly not correct.

### Using bash instead of primitive resources

You are using Bash to echo content into a file. This is a perfect job for the `file` or `template` resources. The will be idempotent and handle notifications properly:

```
file '~/.bash_profile` do
  content <<-EOH
    export JAVA_HOME=$JAVAHOME
    export PATH=$PATH
  EOH
end
```

However, it is worth noting that the script as you have it does nothing. You are setting the values of `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` to themselves. It is likely that you want to use `#{ENV['JAVA_HOME']}` instead.

### Bash is a subshell resource

When you use the `bash` (or any execute resource), you are executing in a subshell, so things like `source` or `export` are not persisted to the parent process.