# Should I install a separate ruby for chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am exploring chef. I want to know whether it is good to have a separate ruby installed for chef using RVM or we should use ruby that comes shipped with chef ??

What is the best practice.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing. For **running** Chef, you should use the embedded Ruby. For any tasks that the Chef Client needs to complete, such as communicating with external services, you should use the embedded Ruby.

For local development, you should use the [ChefDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379943/source-bash-profile-not-taking-effect-with-chef-run), which includes a developer's Ruby.

Comment: see also this blog post from @jtimberman, which explains it quite well: http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2014/04/30/chefdk-and-ruby/

Comment: now what is the differenece between ChefDk and enterprize chef that we normally use

Comment: The difference is that you use ChefDK for developing cookbooks on your workstation. Enterprise chef is your chef server, where the cookbooks are stored and later downloaded by the chef clients.

Comment: I always used external chef as i used it for 'communicating with external services' ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use the version of ruby that comes with chef for running Chef. That version is tested.