# Chef - Source / Refresh environment variables session and make them persistent

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

In a Chef recipe, I need to source a file which sets many environment variables in the node.
Then from the same recipe, another action (package) is run which depends of those other environment variables.
I tried the following but the source action is not persistent so the package action fails requesting missing environment variables.

```
bash "Sourcing ENV Variables" do
  code "source /etc/profile.d/set_env.sh"
end

package "my-package" do
  action :install
end
```

How can I source persistently a file, or refresh the user session so it takes the profile updates (/etc/profile.d/set_env.sh) ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [source bash\_profile not taking effect with chef-run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379943/source-bash-profile-not-taking-effect-with-chef-run)

Comment: I'd also encourage you to look at: http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_environment_variables.html There are multiple options